# Why can not be counted the pipe chars in string?

Tags: sql, regex, oracle, pipe

```
select Values, REGEXP_COUNT(values,'|') from Products
```

Sample Values cell:

```
Product|Cash|Loan|Customer
```

Result of select is **27**. If count any other char it works, but if I want to count the | it counts the whole string. Why, and how can I count the pipes?

Comment: You shouldn't be storing delimited values like that in a single column to begin with

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count specific character you could also use:

```
SELECT col, LENGTH(col) - LENGTH(REPLACE(col, '|')) AS pipe_count
FROM tab;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9b05447894bdda8f53406841970e839d)**

Output:

```
┌────────────────────────────┬────────────┐
│            COL             │ PIPE_COUNT │
├────────────────────────────┼────────────┤
│ Product|Cash|Loan|Customer │          3 │
└────────────────────────────┴────────────┘
```

Answer (score 5):

That's because `|` has a special meaning in regular expressions. If you want them to be read as normal characters you need to escape them, using `\|`.

Comment: Yes, the pipe symbol means OR  see https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/regexp_count.php